# how to run aws cli command silently to create a dynamodb table

Tags: amazon-dynamodb, aws-cli, amazon-dynamodb-local

I am creating a shell script that will create a couple of dynamodb tables locally among other things.
This is the create table AWS CLI command I am using:

```
aws dynamodb create-table --cli-input-json file://table-user.json --endpoint-url http://localhost:8000
```

with table-user.json having all table related information for creation.

The problem with this command is I need to click on key 'q' to proceed to the next line for execution as it gives table details as output.
ex:

```
{
    "TableDescription": {
        "AttributeDefinitions": [
            {
                "AttributeName": "id",
                "AttributeType": "S"
            },
            {
                "AttributeName": "externalId",
                "AttributeType": "S"
            },
.
.
.
```

How can I silently run the create table command?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Set `AWS_PAGER=""`.

So your command would be:

```sh
AWS_PAGER="" aws dynamodb create-table --cli-input-json file://table-user.json --endpoint-url http://localhost:8000
```

Comment: This works for me. Thanks, Chris. In fact I used the export command to set this in the start of  script to avoid multiple entry. export AWS_PAGER=""

Answer (score 0):

If you haven't found any solution in the cli documentation take a look at the unix  [yes command](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Yes_(Unix)).

You can do something like:

```
yes q | aws dynamodb create-table --cli-input-json file://table-user.json --endpoint-url http://localhost:8000
```

This command will keep on entering the specified string (*q* in this case) until the program finishes.

Comment: I tried this solution but does not seems to be working. Still have to click on q when prompted. I am using zsh terminal.